# Can something have multiples of the same aura?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can I have duplicate enchantment auras on the same creature?
Example: I enchanted my Kor Spiritdancer with Ethereal Armor, can I cast another Ethereal Armor on her?

Yes or no, and what's the ruling reference?

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can. The only limit on enchantments is the same limit that all permanents have: the Legendary rule. You can only have 1 permanent in play of a given name if they are legendary.

However, even if you enchant a creature with the same enchantment, subsequent enchantments might not do anything. For example, you can only get lifelink once.

Take your Ethereal Armor example, the power/toughness bonus would stack, and presuming those are your only enchantments on the board, each would provide +2/+2 for a total of +4/+4.  However, granting the First Strike ability on the 2nd enchantment would do nothing, since that ability is already granted by the first enchantment.

Comment: There's also the World limit and various deck-construction limits.

Comment: You could get around the deck construction limits by using something like Clone.  So, for each clone-like card, you could have 4 more of a creature on the battlefield.

Comment: Also because I've seen this question come up more times than it should - no, giving something first strike twice does not give it double strike.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, though providing a rules reference isn't as easy as you think. There isn't a rule that explicitly says you can't enchant a single permanent with multiple copies of the same enchantment. Rather, since it isn't prohibited by the Rules, or specifically made not allowed by a card, you are allowed to do so.

Comment: Thanks so much! I couldn't find anything against it either, but it was sort of a house made rule that some of my friends played by.

Comment: (re: the answer) Well, technically I'd say the rule that allows you to put enchantments on creatures doesn't give any restrictions. I bring this up because the rules of Magic generally work by starting from nothing and specifying what you _can_ do. So if you want to take some action in the game, there had better be a rule that allows you to do so. In this case, there is; there's a rule that lets you put an enchantment on a creature.

Comment: @DavidZ - Rule 303 for enchantments, and the rest of the rules in general, are less about what you can do, and more about how you do it. After a description of how things work, there are a number of circumstances that delineate what can't happen.